# Predicate Logic - Some Days are not Rainy

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The following statement needs to be converted into Predicate logic.

**Some days are not rainy.**

Universe is everything in this world.

Our faculty gave the following answer ->

**$\lnot (\forall  x  D(x) \land R(x)) $**

Where, D(x) means x is a day
And R(x) means x is rainy.

I am somewhat confused with the following answer. I believe it does not match with the statement above.

Comment: Are you sure the for-all operator is inside the parentheses?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. And that is the most shocking part too. The following is according to de morgan's law i guess

¬∀x(φ)⇔∃x¬(φ)

But my faculty is not considering this and I just can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "literal" translation would be
$$\exists x\ (D(x)\wedge \neg R(x))\ .$$
This is equivalent to
$$\neg\forall x\ (\neg D(x)\vee R(x))$$
or
$$\neg\forall x\ (D(x)\to R(x))\ ,$$
but not to the answer they gave.

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. 
∃x (D(x)∧¬R(x)) 
I gave the same answer but my faculty does not agree with it. Says, if you make the truth table of the answer he gave, the answer would be right. But he hasn't made the truth table either or even tried to explain the reasoning behind his answer yet.